# Why distribution of multiple recursive random number generators is uniform?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

I was reading the article of [L'Ecuyer](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pierre_LEcuyer/publication/226589458_Uniform_random_number_generation/links/00463525d7bcc97369000000.pdf) on random number generation.
The title of this article is "Uniform   Random  Number  Generation". One of the proposed PRNGs there, is multiple recursive random number generators added with a constant.

> My question is Why the distribution of a multiple recursive random number generators added with a constant is uniform? I couldn't find a proper reference on the subject.

These random number generators are defined by equation:
$$ x_{n}\equiv a_1x_{n-1}+a_2x_{n-2}+\ldots+a_kx_{n-k}+a\pmod{m}$$

I'm looking specially for the case of $m=2^r$, which a lower hardware complexity is required for its implementation on digital systems.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ real or integers? What is their support, such as  $\{0,1\}$ or $[0,1)$ or $[0,m)$ or $\{0,1,2, \ldots,m-1\}$?

Comment: In MRGs $x_i \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$

Comment: It would be helpful if all the $a_i$ (at the very least, one of them)  were coprime with $m$

Comment: I think this assumption should not be necessary, according to the article of L'Ecuyer. However, in the special case that I'm looking for,i.e. $m=2^r$, the characteristic polynomial of the recursion is primitive modulo $2$ but in general I don't know.

Comment: Well for example if $m=2^r$ and all the $a_i$ are even, that will fix the parity of $x_n$

Comment: For the characteristic polynomial to be primitive, some of $a_i$s must be odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, no deterministic algorithm can generate truly
random numbers. The goal is to find an algorithm that gives
output values that 'behave as if' they are independent and
identically distributed according to some distribution--usually
$Unif(0, 1).$

By 'behave as if' one means that the pseudo-random numbers
pass a large battery of benchmark tests for randomness,
and give correct answers (within random error) to a large
collection of problems known to be difficult to simulate.
If a PRNG fails at one of these tasks, we know it's a 'bad'
one. 'Good' PRNGs are ones that have not been proved bad
after extensive testing. (Beyond the obvious, special
attention is given to checking to see there is no multi-dimensional serial correlation, even in high dimensions.)

Some number-theoretic and other rules are known, telling
kinds of algorithms and specific choices of constants
(e.g, your $a_i$ and $m$) one must always avoid. Other rules
are known for making 'potentially' promising PRNGs, but
one never knows if a particular PRNG is useful until it is
thoroughly vetted.

If you have access to R statistical software, a list of
PRNGs currently regarded as 'good' is available by
typing `? .Random.seed` at the prompt `>` in the Session
window. The default in R is the 'Mersenne-twister', which
has a 'good' record after very extensive use.

There is controversy whether digits far out into the decimal
representation of transcendental numbers such as $e$ and $\pi$
are random, but the controversy is not of practical importance
because it takes too much computing to get vast numbers of
digits rapidly enough for modern simulations.

The best efforts towards truly random numbers have used
physical random noise of various sorts. But these
methods are currently too slow for extensive simulations.
Perhaps somewhere along the line toward the development
of quantum computers a way to generate truly random
values at a very rapid rate will be discovered.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you mean that there is no proof for the fact that  'this random-like behavior is uniform' and these PRNGs are classified to be uniform only by statistical tests?

Comment: No formal mathematical proof. By their good works shall ye know them.

Comment: Do you know a good reference book containing statistical analysis of the subject?

Comment: Most books on simulation have introductory chapters on PRNGs and how they are vetted. Pick one that matches your level of math and computer backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

The definite discussion on congruential random number generation is in Knuth's "Seminumerical Algorithms" (volume 2 of his ["The Art of Computer Programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), Addison-Wesley). Lots of other types of generators have been proposed since, but as far as I know none has undergone the same theoretical and practical scrutiny. The last edition of the book recommends [`ran_array`](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs.html#rng), a portable generator that is freely available (in FORTRAN and C).